# Random variables in conservative differential equations

Tags: probability-distributions, differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations in which a variable converts to several other ones. I'd like to add randomness to the parameters, but I am not sure the best approach.

A minimal example (the real one has more terms) is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= -\Gamma \, x,
&
\Gamma &= \sum_{i = 1}^N \gamma_i,
\\
\frac{dy_i}{dt} &= \gamma_i \, x,
&
i &= 1, 2, \ldots, N.
\end{aligned}
$$

I want $\gamma_i$ to be positive constant random variables, preferabl normally or uniformally distributed around a mean value, for example $\Gamma/N$.

One approach I found was sampling from a Dirichlet distribution of size $N$, but I don't know if it is a good approach.

Comment: It may be easier to choose randomly $N-1$ cut points on the interval $[0,\Gamma]$ (according to some distribution), order the cut points, and compute the $\gamma$s as the lengths of the resulting segments. There's probably some literature on the statistics of the lengths of the resulting segments based on initial choice of distribution for selecting the cut points.